# Can you use linear regression to predict individua or group player performance from team performance in a Public Good Game?

Tags: mixed-model, multiple-regression, predictive-models, linear-model, linear

I am doing an analysis of the experimental data I have collected. In particular, I should do a panel regression.

I have collected data from my experiment on public goods. My variable of interest is Contribution, i.e. the choice of how many tokens to pay to the public good for each participant (0 to 9 maximum). the game for each player lasts 15 rounds, in which they answer the same questions.

I created several treatments and between each treatment we change the MPCR, i.e. the return each participant has from participating (contributing) and thus from donating tokens to the common project.
The data set has three treatments: in the first treatment the players (groups of 2) had an MPCR=0.6 and the response variable is the contribution between 0 and 9. In the second treatment, the MPCR was 0.6. In the second treatment, the MPCR was symmetrical and equal to 0.8. Finally, in the last treatment each group (groups of 2 players) one player had 0.6 and one 0.8. I therefore decided to create 4 categories, i.e. I decided to separate the last treatment into two to improve the analysis and to be able to compare the symmetrical groups as well.

So Homogeneity: means that the MPCRs are the same for both. heterogeneity: means that they are one high and one low within the same group. And MPCR low and high (is a parameter), 0.6 and 0.8.

I wanted to run a ** regression with random effects ** as the treatments are constant and do not change per individual. My variable of interest is contribution and the repressors can be the treatments (A, B, C or D), Period from 1 to 15, the contribution to the previous round, the contribution from the other group member to the previous round etc.
I obviously put the random effects at individual and pair level.

Do you think this is right; should I make changes?